# transform returned ArrayLlist to List that is consistent to form 'Object...name'

Tags: java, arraylist

Hellow

I created a class Packet as followed

```
public class Packet 
{
    private long arrivalTime = 0;
    private boolean classType = true;

    public Packet(long arrivalTime, boolean classType)
    {
        this.arrivalTime = arrivalTime;
        this.classType = classType;
    }
```

In a program I have two methods;

```
public ArrayList<Packet> simulateArrProces (long loopCount)
{
//DO STUFF
}

public void enqueue(Packet...packets)
{
//DO STUFF
}
```

The objective is to use the ArrayList returned by the simulateArrProces method as an input for the enqueue method. I thought I could simply give the ArrayList of the first method, but this doesn't seem to work. I tried the following

```
Arrival arr = new Arrival(arrivalProces);
Queue que = new QueueFCFS();
List l = arr.simulateArrProces(0);
que.enqueue(l.toArray());
```

It is clear that I should tranform the returned ArrayList of simulateArrProces to something, but I don't find what to. I think this is due to the fact that I chose to use ' Packet ... packet ' , but I did not  exactly get what this expression meant.

In short; two questions
1. How to transform the ArrayList returned by simulateArrProces to something I can use in the enqueue method.
2. What is the exact meaning of Packet... packets

Comment: Dont return type ArrayList, instead just return the interface List.

Answer (score 3):

The `toArray` method of `Collection` (from which `List`s and subsequently `ArrayList`s inherit) features an [overload](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(T[])), taking an (empty) array of `T` (your parametrized type) as parameter: this is what you should employ in order not to return an `Object[]`.

In turn, this can be passed into a method taking a varargs of that type as parameter.

**Example**

Given...

```
List<String> foo() {
    // just as example
    return new ArrayList<String>();
}
void bar(String... s) {
    // nope
}
```

Here are the "good" vs "bad" idioms available to you:

```
List<String> foo = foo();
// bad, casting Object[] as String[]
bar((String[])foo.toArray());
// good, populating a String[] of your List's size with your List's elements
bar(foo.toArray(new String[foo.size()]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with **Packet...packets**. It's var-args feature of Java. This means that you can pass there any number of packet objects. Implicitly it converts to array of `Packet` so you can pass an array as well

**Example 1:**

```
class Packet {
  // your implementation goes here
}

class SomeClassWithVarArgs{
   void foo(Packet ... packet);
}


// So you can do the following:


Packet p1 = new Packet();
Packet p2 = new Packet();
Packet p3 = new Packet();

SomeClassWithVarArgs s = new SomeClassWithVarArgs();

// all these are legal
s.foo(p1, p2,p3);
s.foo(p1, p2);
s.foo(p3, p3,p3,p3,p3);

// implicit conversion to array:
Packet [] arrayOfPackets = new Packet[] {p1, p2,p3};
s.foo(arrayOfPackets);
```

Now regarding the toArray, it's just a compilation related issue you'll have to learn.

Obviously you can't pass neither ArrayList not List to `enqueue(Packet... packets)`. So you've tried to convert the list to array and it's a good attempt. However `toArray` returns `Object []` and obviously it's not what you want.

So you should use the following approach:

**Example 2:**

```
List<Packet> li = ...
Packet [] arr = li.toArray(new Packet[li.size()]);

 // now you can pass it to enqueue method
enqueue(arr);
```